# Sorting A-Z but grouping specifc rows in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a quick question regarding my SSRS report.

I currently have a report where I show a list of customers and their balances, sorted from A-Z.

However, there are a 4 customers that I would like to show one after another,

For example,

Adam

Alex

Dean

Brian* <-- I would like Brian and Fernando to be as shown, one after another, while the rest of the list still maintains A-Z

Fernando*

Leonard

Mark

Is this possible? Any input is appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason Dean is before both Brian and David as that is not alphabetical in either case...  That aside, how are you identifying the 4 that need to be shown together?  Are they grouped by some other value in your data?

Comment: This list is just an example. There is no other value that groups them together. I would simply like for them to show one after another in my report, while the rest of the list remains A-Z. I would also like for there to be a total ONLY for these customers, however that is a separate question that i'll ask separately if I have to

Comment: But why these specific customers?  Any solution provided for this issue will require hard coding the customer names/IDs into your query/report which is going to be a pain for future maintenance.  What is it that means they should be next to one another?

Comment: Each customer has a balance. Some customers are related to other customers, therefore, it would be beneficial to see the balances of these customers one after another for proper analysis.

Comment: "Some customers are related to other customers"  This is my question, ***how*** are these customers related to one another?  If it is just in the understanding of your report users, you should really consider putting this information into your database.

Comment: There isn't anything in the database that connects the two. I have created a "Relationship" field where we have manually inputted different customers into different groups. However, this won't work for this specific report. So the only solution requires hard coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Ran into similar problem in the past. I was able to overcome it be sorting the data in SQL using case statement before using it as a dataset in SSRS. See example bellow.

```
;WITH Sort AS 
(
SELECT 'Aiden' AS CustomerName UNION
SELECT 'Jackson'UNION
SELECT 'Ethan'UNION
SELECT 'Liam'UNION
SELECT 'Mason'UNION
SELECT 'Noah'UNION
SELECT 'Lucas 'UNION
SELECT 'Jacob 'UNION
SELECT 'Sophia 'UNION
SELECT 'Emma 'UNION
SELECT 'Olivia 'UNION
SELECT 'Isabella 'UNION
SELECT 'Ava 'UNION
SELECT 'Lily 'UNION
SELECT 'Zoe 'UNION
SELECT 'Chloe 'UNION
------------------
SELECT 'Fernando' UNION
SELECT 'Leonard'UNION
SELECT 'Mark'
)
SELECT
CASE WHEN CustomerName = 'Fernando' THEN 1
     WHEN CustomerName = 'Leonard' THEN 2
     WHEN CustomerName = 'Mark' THEN 3
     Else 4 END AS Sort,
CustomerName
FROM Sort
ORDER BY Sort,CustomerName
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to get your expected should be mapping each customer to a corresponding group:

```
Group   Name 

Group1  Adam
Group2  Alex
Group3  Dean
Group4  Brian
Group4  Fernando
Group5  Mark
```

Then in your tablix you can create a group, it will show names in the same group one each other. Also you can get only one balance total by use something like this:

```
=SUM(Fields!Balance.Value,"Group")
```

However if you don't want to create a group, you can hardcode the names in a conditional sorting expression:

In your Tablix Properties / Sorting tab add a new soting expression and use:

```
=Switch(Fields!Name.Value="Brian","Brian1",
Fields!Name.Value="Fernando","Brian2",
true, Fields!Name.Value
)
```

You will get this:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.